# How to use custum controls with blur Google Maps JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to make a very simple UI over a full screen map with Google Maps. I would like to have a blurred map and a button that takes away the blur when clicked. I basically have that functionality with my current code (heavily based on [this example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-custom)), but the control div is blurred along with the map. I have searched far and wide for examples like this, at one point playing around with z-indexing and stuff with no luck. How can I blur the map element while having a non blur control element on the map as well?

Here is my code:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
center: {lat: 0, lng: 0},
zoom: 3,
minZoom: 3,
disableDefaultUI: true,
mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
styles:[
    {
        "featureType": "road",
        "stylers": [
            { "visibility": "off" }
        ]
    },{
        "featureType": "transit",
        "stylers": [
            { "visibility": "off" }
        ]
    }]
});

function Control(controlDiv, map) {

    // Set CSS for the control border.
    var controlUI = document.createElement('div');
    controlUI.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
    controlUI.style.border = '2px solid #fff';
    controlUI.style.borderRadius = '3px';
    controlUI.style.boxShadow = '0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3)';
    controlUI.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    controlUI.style.marginBottom = '22px';
    controlUI.style.textAlign = 'center';
    controlUI.title = 'Click to recenter the map';
    controlDiv.appendChild(controlUI);

    // Set CSS for the control interior.
    var controlText = document.createElement('div');
    controlText.style.color = 'rgb(25,25,25)';
    controlText.style.fontFamily = 'Roboto,Arial,sans-serif';
    controlText.style.fontSize = '16px';
    controlText.style.lineHeight = '38px';
    controlText.style.paddingLeft = '5px';
    controlText.style.paddingRight = '5px';
    controlText.innerHTML = 'Blur';
    controlUI.appendChild(controlText);

    controlUI.addEventListener('click', function() {
        document.getElementById('map').setAttribute("style", "transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;" +
                                                    "-webkit-transition-duration: 1.5s;" +
                                                    "-webkit-filter: blur(0px);");
        ControlDiv.style.display = 'none';
    });

}

var ControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
new Control(ControlDiv, map);

map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.CENTER].push(ControlDiv);
```

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4mtyu/1795/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why make it a map control? One option would be to make it a separate div from the map and position it over the map.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4mtyu/1796/)

[image: picture of map with blur control on top]

**code snippet:**

```js
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  center: {
    lat: 0,
    lng: 0
  },
  zoom: 3,
  minZoom: 3,
  disableDefaultUI: true,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
  styles: [{
    "featureType": "road",
    "stylers": [{
      "visibility": "off"
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "transit",
    "stylers": [{
      "visibility": "off"
    }]
  }]
});

function Control(controlDiv, map) {

  // Set CSS for the control border.
  var controlUI = document.createElement('div');
  controlUI.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
  controlUI.style.border = '2px solid #fff';
  controlUI.style.borderRadius = '3px';
  controlUI.style.boxShadow = '0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3)';
  controlUI.style.cursor = 'pointer';
  controlUI.style.marginBottom = '22px';
  controlUI.style.textAlign = 'center';
  controlUI.title = 'Click to recenter the map';
  controlDiv.appendChild(controlUI);

  // Set CSS for the control interior.
  var controlText = document.createElement('div');
  controlText.style.color = 'rgb(25,25,25)';
  controlText.style.fontFamily = 'Roboto,Arial,sans-serif';
  controlText.style.fontSize = '16px';
  controlText.style.lineHeight = '38px';
  controlText.style.paddingLeft = '5px';
  controlText.style.paddingRight = '5px';
  controlText.innerHTML = 'Click';
  controlUI.appendChild(controlText);

  controlUI.addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('map').setAttribute("style", "transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;" +
      "-webkit-transition-duration: 1.5s;" +
      "-webkit-filter: blur(0px);");
    ControlDiv.style.display = 'none';
  });

}

var ControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
new Control(ControlDiv, map);
document.getElementById('blurctl').appendChild(ControlDiv);
// map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.CENTER].push(ControlDiv);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map {
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-filter: blur(12px);
}
#blurctl {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="blurctl"></div>
```